# What time era is presented in Gotham?

Tags: gotham

In *Gotham*, Gordan said that he participated in war, technology shown is not too old. But still which time era it represents looks vague. Is it ever said which time era it represents?

Comment: Related question on [scifi.se]: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68219/23386.

Comment: Ahhh.....forgot to check Scifi.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you didn't, of course.

Comment: how could harvey bullock have such a slim, flip mobile phone in 70s or 80s? It is really confusing. This detective has his own mobile phone, everyone else uses the vintage telephone sets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I actually posed a similar question (and [answered it myself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68220/31029)) on https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ because I was anticipating it.

Gotham showrunner Bruno Heller [explained this to Entertainment Weekly](http://insidetv.ew.com/2014/07/20/gotham-fox-batman-prequel/) some time ago:

> Gotham is not set in any particular time period: Okay, this has been
>   out there a bit, but Heller had a nice quote elaborating on the show’s
>   timeless quality: “It’s a mash-up, to use the modern phrase,” he said.
>   “If today Batman exists, then this world is the past. But it’s
>   everybody’s past, an 18-year-old’s past and a 54-year-old’s past. So
>   in your memory, the past is all mashed up together. So in this Gotham,
>   it’s a kind of timeless world. It’s yesterday, it’s today, and it’s
>   tomorrow all at the same time, because that’s the world that dreams
>   live in.”

Comment: The city of Gotham has been depicted in many different ways to suit the needs of whomever is writing the story/stories. They went with a sort of art deco theme for `Batman: The Animated Series` to give it a sort of classic look, but they had computers and large screen TVs all throughout the city. So yeah, that too played to the timeless aspect of Gotham, so viewers could see it in any sort of time frame they wanted. Plus it lets them get away with some of the fantastical gadgets Batman and others use. No one can say, "They couldn't do that in the 60s," if you don't establish a period.

Comment: @MattD Indeed, the *Animated Series* with its strange mix of 40s art deco with current tech was the first thing that sprang to my mind when reading this whole *Gotham* discussion, as I remember that I always wondered what time they were actually depicting in the *Animated Series*.

Comment: Gets even weirder when you hit `Batman Beyond` (aka `Batman of the Future` in most European markets, I believe) and everything is really future tech.

Answer (score 2):

I think Gotham, the tv show, is supposed to take place in the same time period as ours, but in a different dimension than our own. It is supposed to be familiar but with small differences, like they have cell phones, but they use 70s technology like overhead projectors and microfilm readers. And of course the 70s-style cars.