# What time period is Pennyworth set in?

Tags: pennyworth

Pennyworth is about Batman's butler, Alfred Pennyworth, in his younger days.

It seems like an odd mix of time periods. 1960s clubs and cars, music from the 70s and 80s, public executions from the 1800s, airships from the 30s.

More random details: Cliff Richard and The Shadows breaking up is current news (1968) but also the Reich is apparently still a thing (1930s).

When is it supposed to be set?

Comment: Related: [What time era is presented in Gotham?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/24806/49) Together with *The Animated Series* they seem to have a penchant for ambiguous chronologic and stylistic settings.

Comment: It's an alternate history. https://www.cbr.com/pennyworth-tv-gotham-timeline/ See also: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24806/what-time-era-is-presented-in-gotham

Comment: Thanks for that link. I will stop searching for the dates of release of the songs I hear in this show soundtrack now that I’ve read your comment.

Answer (score 4):

### It's the 1960's...but an *alternate reality*.

From an [interview with the producers](https://www.dccomics.com/blog/2019/09/06/secret-war-pennyworths-producers-on-building-the-shows-world)...

> For the first time ever, we could create a DC-style **1960s England**. I was worried at the beginning that we wouldn't know who the villains would be, but when you mine British history and **you decide you’re going to alter British history because this is an alternative DC reality**, it's very close. It's only 13 degrees off. What happened to Jack the Ripper's family? What happened to Myra Hindley? When you start to realize that Guy Fawkes and all of these mythological characters and characters from British history are available to us, then you go, “Wow, that's an interesting bunch of villains.”

Comment: were they intend to us Guy Fawkes as a villian?